# Handle file upload progress on recyclerview item while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a chat application. It has a chat activity similar to WhatsApp, This app has features like sending text messages and files(images/pdf/doc, etc.). We are using recyclerview for message list in chat activity. Recyclerview on chat activity has multiple view types like textview for text message and imageview for images and few other custom views for another file types like DOC and PDF. We have a custom view class for view type file. When a user sends a file (image, pdf, doc etc.) a view is created according to file type.

When a user sends a file to another user a new view is created and added to the list, we are also showing file uploading status like **uploading-in-progress**, **uploading-failed**, **uploading-success** on the chat item.

We are facing an issue here while a user sending multiple files to another user, and scroll the screen up and down, the views are re-cycled and the positions of views are changes, therefore while showing uploading status, we lost the older view on which the uploading starts. Now we have another view instance on that position.

Therefore, after scrolling the uploading progress is showing on another view. We just wants to show the uploading status on right place where it was before the scrolling.

We have tried out few ways like setting

recyclerview.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE_FILE, 0);

It makes recylerview to not recycle the view file type ,but it makes the recylcerview scrolling very slow.

Kindly help with a solution. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it is supposed to work. You should configure a recycled views to match the objects it represents now. If you do nothing it shows the object it represented previously. So every time you are asked to provide a view and you are given a recycled view, you need to get the corresponding object from your collection and replace all visualized information in the recycled view with the information of the object it should represent now. I assume in your case the object is a message.

Comment: There are many examples already exsisting. Like https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview. What I mean you can find simplified in onBindViewHolder(..).